# open a file of any type in ios, swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Swift based iOS app, and need to be able to open a file of any file type.
I tried,

```
let types = UTType.types(tag: "*", tagClass: UTTagClass.filenameExtension, conformingTo: nil)
let modelPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: types)
```

But does not work...
How to allow any file type?

Code that worked was,

```
let types = [UTType.item]
let modelPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: types)
```

Comment: Have you tried using just [data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551482-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You very likely want [`UITType.item`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551521-item) here (which is the identifier `public.item`).

> A generic base type for most objects, such as files or directories.

You should spend some time looking over the docs for [Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers). You may find other types that more closely match your intention.